# get auth user into vuejs object

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

i want to get my current logged user details into my hidden input fields. so i write input values like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" v-model="comment.name">
<input type="hidden" name="avatar" v-model="comment.avatar">
```

or i want to get directly user informations into my vuejs objects

```
comment: {                  
          name: '',
          avatar: '',
          user_id: '',
          comment: '',
          status: 'Approved',
          created_at: ''
        },
```

how i get current logged user details into this object. i used this fetch method to get details

```
axios.get("api/userdetails").then(({ data }) => (this.users.fill(data)));
```

this is my controller

```
return auth('api')->user();
```

Comment: why are you doing `this.users.fill(data)`?

Comment: @ Boussadjra Brahim i want to show my current user data into my vuejs objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get current authenticated user id using Vuejs and Laravel**

*You Should add to* `<meta name="user-id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">` in

> // app.blade.php or  whatever you have maybe master.blade.php like below

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        @if (Auth::check()) 
          <meta name="user-id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
        @endif 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" 
      ...
      ..
```

Then in the app.js or main.js add

```
 data: {
    comment: {
      name: '',
      cart: '',
      user_id: document.querySelector("meta[name='user-id']").getAttribute('content'),
    },
```

> // Finally in your MyVueComponent.vue

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="comment.name" class="form-control" required>
    <input type="hidden" v-model="comment.cart">
    <input type="hidden" v-model="comment.user_id">
</div>
```

hope will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the user variables straight into the blade template in the vuejs object?

`{{ Auth::user()->id }}
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}`

Etc

Comment: how can i bind this with my objects

Answer (score 0):

If i understood this well, this.users is list of all users you have in your, let's say, state? If this is true, then you have to recognize your currently logged user by some unique id he has, maybe you should use this.users.filter to find that user and compare id with currently logged user. Then just grab field you need to fill.

Comment: no i try to get current user details and bind it to users array objects

Comment: So currently logged user is something like Auth::user()->id etc, append it to this.users with spread operator : this.users = [...this.users, ...Auth::user()];

Comment: how can i write it